# Increase Ubuntu 16.04 Partition Size

Tags: 16.04, partitioning, windows, gparted

I installed Ubuntu 16.04 alongside Windows, giving it 50 Gb of space. Now, I need more space. I'm using gParted and I managed to unallocate a piece of partition. How can I extend Ubuntu with the space I reserved?
Many thanks

[image]

Comment: You can't resize a partition when it's mounted and root partition can't be unmounted, it can be done from Live USB ubuntu mode (but i'm not sure that's why i just posted comment)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an easy one...

## Backup any data on your Ubuntu partition, as this procedure could corrupt or loose data.

- Boot to a Ubuntu Live DVD/USB in "Try Ubuntu" mode
- start `gparted` from the Unity dashboard
- right-click on sda8 in the lower pane and select **resize**
- hover the mouse pointer over the left side of sda8 until it turns into a directional pointer
- click and drag the left side of sda8 all the way left
- click OK to close the move/resize window
- click the `Apply` icon